# why can't i use () behind except in Python2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, except, raise

I have the following code - I've commented next to the line where I don't understand the results.

```
class A:
    pass;
class B(A):
    pass;
class C(B):
    pass;

for i in [A,B,C]:
    try:
        raise i();
    except C:
        print("C");
    except B:
        print("B");
    ### if i write A(), it shows: __main__.A: <__main__.A instance at 0x00ACBE18>
    except A:
        print("A");
```

This is my first time using the site, so please let me know if anything requires clarification...

Comment: What is this even asking?

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: The question is on the title and as a comment of code.

Comment: Drop all those semicolons, Python doesn't need them.

Comment: What are you trying to do by writing `A()` ?

Answer (score 4):

`A` is a class. when you write A() you actually instantiate the class `A`

When you raise an instance of class `A` as an exception (when `i = A`), 
there is no `except` clause that will catch this instance when it is written like this `A()`

So what that you see: `__main__.A: <__main__.A instance at 0x00ACBE18>` is the instance that has been raise and no one catches it.

You actually can use `()` in. try it on C().

```
class A: 
    pass
class B(A): 
    pass 
class C(B):
    pass

for i in [A,B,C]: 
    try: 
        raise i()
    except C(): 
        print("C")
    except B:
        print("B")
    except A:
        print("A")
```

Will output:

```
A
B
B
```

You can read more about errors and exceptions in python [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html).